# Helm Charts : XOR on string

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to build a Helm Chart. There's a value (db.password) that sometimes should be passed as plain text, and other times as XOR+Base64.

I don't want to set two values, one for plain and another for encoded password, so I was trying do code a template function to do the encoding. Since [sprigs already has base64 encoding](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/encoding.html), I've figured all I'd have to do was a XOR function... I already have a shell script for that, how hard could it be to port it to my template right?

I'm trying to iterate throught every charater of the string and XORing it:

```
{{- define "encrypt.decrypt" -}}
{{- $key := 95 -}}
{{- range $k,$v := splitList "" .password }}
{{- printf "%s"  (add (atoi (quote $v)) $key | toString) -}}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

And then I'd call it like that:

```
{{include "encrypt.decrypt" (dict "Values" .Values "password" .Values.db.password) }}
```

But all it does is print is 95 a lot of times. The convertion of an non-numeric character to int is not working and defaulting to 0.

`atoi (quote $v))` is just returning 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need a couple of pieces that aren't in either [the core text/template functionality](https://godoc.org/text/template) or [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) and this turns out to not be reasonably possible.

The two big shortcomings I see:

- `splitList "" .password` produces a list of single-character strings.  That's useful, but there's no way to further reduce that to a list of Unicode code point values.  Of note `atoi $v` will try to read a string as a number; it would understand the string `"17"` but doesn't know that `"a"` should become 97.
- The only arithmetic functions available [come from Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/math.html) but those don't include any bitwise operations.

If you're only dealing with printable ASCII, one hacky thing you could do is build a static map from each character to its XOR:

```
{{- $xorMap := dict "!" "~" "~" "!"
                    "\"" "{" "{" "\""
                    "#" "|" "|" "#" ... -}}
```

Then inside your `range` loop, `index` each character into this lookup map.  If you have another way to validate the obfuscation, it's worth double-checking this (via `helm template`, for example).

If you already have a shell script that can do this it might be easier to configure the Docker container that eventually gets run to do this at startup time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought at first, but didn't want to believe in, so I decided to come to SO.

Comment: Have to weight this 3 options:
- hacky dict apporach should work, but might become a maitenance burden (edge cases, missing characters, XOR key change);
- change app image to handle that at startup with the shell script I already have. But changes at the official base image might break that, so it also could become a maintenance burden;
- using 2 values for encoded and plain password at values.yaml and document it properly, shifting the burden to the end user.
Anyways, thanks for your answer, I'll mark it as correct.